# Dynamic Json - Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, json.net

I'm trying to access a child value in my json, which looks like this

```
{
"event": "InstanceCreated",
"destination": "application",
"data": "{\"pipelineId\":1,\"requestId\":1,\"pid\":24740}" 
}
```

It's a string I get from an external process.
I'm trying to access the requestId value doing

```
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s1);
var id = json.data.requestId;
```

But what I get is the exception mentioned in the title. I've read all of the similar issues but I couldn't find anything that solved mine. I thought about the issue where you could have too many escape chars like \ but it's not my case and doing Regex.Unescape won't do because it makes the string unparsable.
I have also tried using JObject.Parse(s1) or any other class related parsing method but I always get that exception.

I can access some values of that json, doing things like

```
json.@event
json.destination
json.data
```

correctly returns me the associated value.

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json and Unity3D

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data field is not an object with the 3 properties as you expect, but just a string in the way it's formatted now. You either need to get a proper format from the source or deserialize the string seperately to access the properties.

What it should look like to get the expected result:

```
{
    "event": "InstanceCreated",
    "destination": "application",
    "data": {
        "pipelineId": 1,
        "requestId": 1,
        "pid": 24740
    }
}
```

Comment: What you mean is that I need to have it formatted with the new lines inside the data token? I thought that deserializing or parsing wouldn't take into account the format as long as it was a proper json

Comment: The formatting indeed does not matter, but look carefully at what data holds. It's no longer a string (see difference between `{ ... }` and `"{ ... }"`).Your data property holds a string and not a structure with 3 properties. Right now it's a json in a json.

Comment: Ah! Didn't notice, thank you very much, I'll work on the formatting then